# Programming bootloader section of flash with avrdude is slow

Tags: avr, bootloader, atmel, avrdude

When programming the bootloader section of flash memory in a ATmega 8-bit processor, specifically the ATmega128, AVRdude is rather slow.

All I want to write is the bootloader section of memory, which is in the upper addresses of flash memory.  Because of this, AVRdude wants to write the entire flash memory (128K), rather than just jumping to the bootloader section of memory and writing the bootloader only (say 3K).

Is there any way to speed up the programming process (i.e. jumping to that offset in memory and writing only that section), or am I stuck with a slow programming process?

**EDIT:** I believe that the programmer that I was using was causing the issue.  When I use a different (better) programmer, avrdude just jumps to the offset in flash memory to write the bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem as you. Apparently that's a feature of `avrdude` and I found absolutely no way to get it working.

The solution was to use a command line tool called `jtagice.exe`. It comes with Avr Studio but maybe you can find it on the internet? For an 8Kb bootloader it took something like 10 s with verification.

Comment: I believe that the programmer that I was using was causing the issue. When I use a different (better) programmer, avrdude just jumps to the offset in flash memory to write the bootloader.